# SimpleDateFormat does not throw IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

I want to check date pattern like this :

```
try{
     new SimpleDateFormat(pattern)
} catch(IllegalArgumentException e){}
```

but it seems when I try to add "aaa", it does not fail :(

Comment: Try to catch Exception too. It will overpower any kind of exception your block of code might do. If that does not catch any exception, there might be some issues with the thing you call pattern that you're providing

Comment: Maybe it is a correct pattern.

Comment: While debugging solutions, always try to fit the catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e.Message)} So you'll know exactly what type of error you're causing. This might to see if what you're trying to catch is what you're actually catching !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I try to add "aaa", it does not fail

That's because [according to the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) `a` is the AM/PM marker.

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("aaa");
System.out.println(f.format(new Date()));
// Prints "AM"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I just put this aaa string without any thinking! Such a shame

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting an exception thrown because you are using one of the markers defined in the javadocs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can see the exception thrown by putting something like "ppp" into the constructor, as "p" is not a valid marker for the `SimpleDateFormat`

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ppp");
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```